# How to style posts in bootstrap card column

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bootstrap-4

I have this code for posts that I want to show in bootstrap card column format.

```
%h4{:align => "center"} All Posts
%hr.my-3
- @posts.each do |post|
  %h4= link_to post.title, post
  %p= post.description
  %p= post.company
```

I want to show the first post in one card and the next in the other consistently across the whole page. Seems with the bootstrap code I need to manually input the individual posts. I would want it to be automated. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the HTML please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="card-columns" >
@posts.each do |post|
     <div class="card" >
         <div  class="card-body" >
               access your posts here
         </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.